# Error generating new tokens in a private chain

Tags: interest-rate

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;


// ERC20 Token Smart Contract
contract MyToken {
    string public constant name = "MyToken";
    string public constant symbol = "MYT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 0;
    uint public _totalSupply = 1000000;
    uint256 public RATE = 1;
    bool public isMinting = false;
    string public constant generatedBy  = "Togen.io by Proof Suite";

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address public owner;

    // Functions with this modifier can only be executed by the owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if(msg.sender != owner) {
            throw;
        }
        _;
    }

    // Balances for each account
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    // Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;

    // Its a payable function works as a token factory.
    function () payable {
        createTokens();
    }

    // Constructor
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender; 
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
    }

    //allows owner to burn tokens that are not sold in a crowdsale
    function burnTokens(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(_value);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    }

    // This function creates Tokens  
    function createTokens() payable {
        if(isMinting == true) {
            require(msg.value > 0);
            uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(msg.value);
        }
        else {
            throw;
        }
    }

    function endCrowdsale() onlyOwner {
        isMinting = false;
    }

    function changeCrowdsaleRate(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
        RATE = _value;
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns(uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    // What is the balance of a particular account?
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account   
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
    // The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
    // tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
    // fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
    // deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
    // these standardized APIs for approval:
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns(bool) {
        require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
    // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns(bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; 
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns(uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

I generated a token contract with the [Togen](https://www.togen.io) utility. And it seems that it works fine. The approvals, transfers and getters work fine. But when I'm trying to generate new tokens calling the function from remix tells me that the constructor should be payable. But I cant call that function

**EDIT:**
        // Its a payable function works as a token factory.
        function () payable {
            createTokens(msg.value);
        }

```
    // This function creates Tokens  
    function createTokens(uint256 value) private /*payable*/ {
        if(isMinting == true) {
            require(value > 0);
            uint256 tokens = value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(value);
        }
        else {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I hardcode de value inside a variable. But the problem persist. *Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.*

```
    // This function creates Tokens  
    function createTokens() payable {
        if(isMinting == true) {
            uint testValue = 6666;
            require(/*msg.value*/testValue > 0);
            uint256 tokens = /*msg.value*/testValue.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(/*msg.value*/testValue);
        }
        else {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Apparently you sent a zero value transaction (see wei= 0 in the pic) to the function createTokens() cited and you have a specific require:

```
 require(msg.value > 0);
```

that fire.

So it reverts.

[image]

Your constructor does not require to be payable.

**edit after comments**

I can suggest to comment out the last line (owner.transfer...) if you want to simulate the mechanism via hard coded values (I.e. “6666”). If you succeed in not having zero from the token number calculation, it will easily works.

**edit again**

```
 // This function creates Tokens  
function createTokens() payable {
    if(isMinting == true){
        uint testValue = 666600000000000000;
        require(/*msg.value*/ testValue > 0);
        uint256  tokens = /*msg.value*/testValue.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
       // owner.transfer(/*msg.value*/testValue);
    }
    else{
        throw;
    }
}
```

This can work.

Comment: But if this contract is going to be deploy in a private chain. I can´t call to createTokens() and send the amount that I want to increase the token total balance. I don´t want to use ethre, wei etc. Just send the quantity and update the total balance

Comment: The division which calculates the number of tokens give zero. In uint math 6666/any number greater than 6666 is zero. Moreover the owner.transfer is used to transfer ether, isn’t it? You want transfer tokens. So it cannot succeed in the way you suppose to. You should call “transfer(_to, value)” being the owner of tokens.

Comment: But I don´t want to transfer the tokens to account A to b. Or change ether to contract-token. The idea is call to a function. Send like a parameter the amount of new coins that the contract owner wants to add. And when I call to totalSupply get the original 1000000 tokens + the 6666 new tokens. Total 1006666. It seems that actually the  createTokens function change the ether/wei value to contract tokens?? Or im wrong and with this function can I make what I want?? Thx

Comment: May be you have not so clear the mechanism you are trying to build up. I do not understand how to help you giving answers here. I’d like to reccomend a little further research on the matter, in particular regarding the payable mechanism and its consequence. What you want to obtain is simple to write, but apparently some information are missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Its a payable function works as a token factory.
function () payable{
    createTokens();
}

// This function creates Tokens  
 function createTokens() payable {
    if(isMinting == true){
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    else{
        throw;
    }
}
```

If you try to invoke the `createTokens` function via the callback function (i.e., by sending Ether to the contract), then inside the `createTokens` function, `msg.value` is already 0.

You can resolve this as follows:

- Declare the `createTokens` function as a `private` function which takes `uint256 value` as input
- Replace every occurrence of `msg.value` in this function with `value`
- Get rid of the `payable` modifier in the declaration of this function
- When you call it from the fallback function, pass `msg.value`

Comment: Now don´t appear the function to execute in Remix. But why I have to pass the msg.value. is not supossed that now the value is "value"?? thx

Comment: This is incorrect: "If you try to invoke the createTokens function via the [fallback] function (i.e., by sending Ether to the contract), then inside the createTokens function, msg.value is already 0." The amount of ether sent is always available in `msg.value`, no matter what the chain of function calls.